# Ionic 1 - ngCordovaNativeStorage issue?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ngcordova, cordova-nativestorage

how's it going?

I've using this plugin for a long time, but today I needed to do some notifications in my app. I need to store my data in device and then, when I got internet connection, I'll send this for my servers. But ok, this is not important.

What I'm trying to do is:

- Get my data from server;
- Store my data in device using nativeStorage;

**Getting data and putting in my storage**

```
myFactory.getMyData().then(function(success) {
      $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem("mydata", success);
    }, function(err) {...});
```

OK, my data was correctly stored. Next I'll loop in thru this data and show in view.

```
$cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("mydata").then(function (success)
    {
      for (var i in success)
      {
          $scope.myData.push(success[i]);
      }
    }, function (err){
      getMyData(); // function who will get my data from server
    });
```

OK until now. 
Next I'll send this data to another view and show my data. But when I do ANY modifications in that data (even if I change directly in object or in nativeStorage), that modification do not persists if I back to the main view.

```
$cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("myData").then(function (success){
      success[myIndex].anyProperty = 'abc';
    });
```

Is that a bug or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling $cordovaNativeStorage.setItem(), Native storage actually save JSON string rather than JSON object.Same with $cordovaNativeStorage.getItem(), it will return JSON string. Thus, you must parse it first before manipulating the object .

```
$cordovaNativeStorage.getItem("myData").then(function (jsonString){
      if (jsonString) {
         var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
         jsonObj.anyProperty = 'abc';
      }
    });
```

Comment: Actually, in my factory I'm returning an Object (MyObjectFactory, for example). But if I understood, cordovaNativeStorage converts that object in an JSON string, correct?